# Cannot mimic the action of `echo` command in C code

Tags: c, bash, serial-port, echo, cat

I have written a couple of bash script files that communicate via two serial ports. One script can be thought of as a receiver and the other as a transmitter. The receiving script reads and displays data line by line until it reads the character sequence `<break>`. It then stops listening, and sends a character sequence of either `one` or `two` back to the transmitter. The script is thus:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read and reply bash script.

exec 3<> /dev/ttyS4
while true; do
    #cat -v /dev/ttyS4 | while read -r input; do
    while read -r -u 3 input; do
        if [ "$input" = "<break>" ]
        then
            echo "break command received."
            break
        else
            echo -e "${input}"
        fi
    done 

    echo "Sending selection"
    if [ "$selection" = "one" ]
    then
        selection="two"
    else
        selection="one"
    fi
    echo "$selection" >&3

done
```

The transmitter script transmits some character data and then waits for the reply of `one` or `two` from the receiver script above:

```
exec 4<> /dev/ttyS0
selection="one"
while true; do
    echo "************************************" > /dev/ttyS0
    echo "       Selection: ${selection}" > /dev/ttyS0
    echo "************************************" > /dev/ttyS0
    echo "<break>" > /dev/ttyS0
    read -r -t 3 -u 4 input
    if [ -z "$input" ]
    then
        echo "Response from remote timed out."
    elif [ "$input" = "one" ]
    then
        selection=$input
    elif [ "$input" = "two" ]
    then
        selection=$input
        colour=$RED
    else
        echo "Unknown selection: $input"
    fi

    sleep 1 
done
```

The above two scripts work fine and the receiver script correctly identifies the `<break>` character sequence.

I wish to replace the 'transmitter' script with a small C program however I find that when I send the character sequence `<break>` the receiver script this time does *NOT* identify is as the 'end-of-transmission', is simple echos `<break>` to stdout, and NOT `break command received`. I have tried several things such as adding escape characters but there is obviously something different about the way Bash `echo` works and how I send the data in my C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int selected_tool = DEFAULT_TOOL_SELECTION;
    FILE *ser2_fd_write, *ser2_fdrw;
    struct termios tios, tios_w;        // ser 2 termios structure
    int ser2_fd, ser2_fdw;
    char read_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    struct timespec tdelay;

    bzero(&tdelay, sizeof(tdelay));
    tdelay.tv_sec = 1;
    tdelay.tv_nsec = 5000;

    if ((ser2_fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR)) == -1){
        printf("Unable to open ttyS0 as read-write only.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    bzero(&tios, sizeof(tios));
    cfsetispeed(&tios, B38400);
    cfsetospeed(&tios, B38400);


    tios.c_cflag = B38400 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD | CRTSCTS;
    tios.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
    tios.c_oflag = 0;
    tios.c_lflag = ICANON; //0
    tios.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tios.c_cc[VMIN] = 10;

    tcflush(ser2_fd, TCIFLUSH);
    if (tcsetattr(ser2_fd, TCSANOW, &tios) == -1){
        printf("Could not set ser 2 attributes.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((ser2_fdrw = fdopen(ser2_fd, "awr")) == NULL){
        printf("Unable to open file descriptor.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

while(1){

    push_to_ser2(ser2_fdrw, selected_tool);
    /*
     * This is where sending <break> differs from echo
     */

    //fputs("break", ser2_fdrw);
    fprintf(ser2_fdrw, "break\r\n");
    //fprintf(ser2_fdrw, "\r\n");
    //write(ser2_fd,"break\r\n", 9);
    fflush(ser2_fdrw);
    int c = 0;

    nanosleep(&tdelay, NULL);
    tcflush(ser2_fd, TCIOFLUSH);
    tcdrain(ser2_fd);
    fcntl(ser2_fd, F_SETFL, 0);

    if ( (c = read(ser2_fd, read_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0){
        read_buffer[c] = 0;
        if (strcmp(read_buffer, "one\r\n") == 0){
            selected_tool = 1;
        } else if (strcmp(read_buffer, "two\r\n") == 0){
            selected_tool = 2;
        }
    }else{

    }
}
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


/*
 * Convenience function to push data to ser 2
 * *c_data      pointer to the card data
 * *t_data      pointer to the tool data
 */
void push_to_ser2(FILE * fd, int tool){

    fprintf(fd, "**********************************************************\n");
    fprintf(fd, "*                                                        *\n");
    fprintf(fd, "*                     Tool %d Data                       *\n", tool);
    fprintf(fd, "*                                                        *\n");
    fprintf(fd, "**********************************************************\n");


    fprintf(fd,"\r\n");
    fflush(fd);
}
```

I've tried various alterations to the `termios` struct too but it makes no difference. Any ideas?

Comment: Several issues with your code: Instead of `bzero(&tios, sizeof(tios))` you should be calling **tcgetattr()**.  Instead of direct assignments, the code should be performing bit-wise operations.  You're specifying non-canonical output with canonical input.  The `read(ser2_fd,...)` is ignoring errors . Instead of using **fdopen()** and **fprintf()**, just use **write(ser2_fd, ...)**.  See
[Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html) and [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)

Comment: Hi sawdust. Thanks for that and the links, especially the last one. by suing the `stty` command I can now make my C code work or fail depending upon what I set. Your info an links has help me get a better understanding of serial port settings. If you put a full answer I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code that should be corrected:

- Instead of `bzero(&tios, sizeof(tios))` the code should be calling **tcgetattr()** to properly initialize the structure.  This can be a serious issue for canonical input, as the existing code will have zeroed out all of the control code specifications instead of having proper definitions.
- Instead of direct assignments, the code should be performing bit-wise operations (in order to preserve existing settings).  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Modes.html).
- You're specifying non-canonical output with canonical input, which is an atypical combination.  Seems like you want canonical mode for both input and output.
- VMIN and VTIME are only meaningful for non-canonical input, and should not be specified for canonical input (as it clobbers the VEOF and VEOL character specifications).
- The `read(ser2_fd,...)` is silently ignoring errors.
- Instead of using **fdopen()** and **fprintf()**, just use **write(ser2_fd, ...)** to simplify the code and overhead.   Downsides are that you'll have to specify the byte counts and use **sprintf()** to perform integer to string conversion.

See [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/%7Estrupp/serial.html).

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the bash script is sending the literal string `<break>`, angle brackets included. Meanwhile, the C program is only sending `break`. Add the angle brackets to the literal in the C program. (Those brackets don't have any special meaning to either `echo` or `fprintf`, so they just get sent as-is.)

Comment: No, it's sending the angle brackets as the receiver script prints `<break>` which means it has fallen through the `if..then..else` in the receiver script

Comment: What behavior, exactly, do you expect, and what do you observe?